# drag divs/lessons and get the position of each

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a course platform site, each course can have many lessons.

In the database, each lesson has a column named `position`, so for the end user, just make a query listing in order by `position`, then they would be displayed in the right order.

The problem is in the admin panel, after registering all the classes, I would like to organize the classes by dragging them to the position I want and then saving, as in this example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L__uKtZXrSC3huhoCuZ-AaKlPOCPtC3U/view?usp=sharing

in my dashboard, the HTML and CSS looks like this

```css
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #232323;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1rem 0px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box" position="1">lesson 1 - learn HTML</div>
<div class="box" position="2">lesson 2 - learn CSS</div>
<div class="box" position="3">lesson 3 - learn JavaScript</div>
```

So how do I drag divs/lessons, always keeping the `position attribute` with the correct value of the position the div is in?

Comment: Consider using a JavaScript library for this, such as [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/).

Comment: @mfluehr With this library I can't get the current position, whether div is literally first div on screen or not, I can only get the original order.

Comment: @YungSilva using SortableJS will work. On the button that you use to save, when that is clicked, simply loop through the "box" divs and you can use a counter to determine their position, the position attribute isn't relevant.

Comment: @imvain2, how can i go through the divs and get her position? can you do an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) library makes it easy to drag elements around. [Detailed library options are explained here.](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options)

The snippet below gives a simple demo of how you can determine which element was just dragged, and get its index.

```js
new Sortable(example, {
  animation: 150,
  onEnd: (e) => {
    console.log(e.item, e.oldIndex, e.newIndex);
    // Now save the new order, as needed
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #232323;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1rem 0px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.9.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div class="box" position="1">lesson 1 - learn HTML</div>
  <div class="box" position="2">lesson 2 - learn CSS</div>
  <div class="box" position="3">lesson 3 - learn JavaScript</div>
</div>
```